# TCL program not creating .pyc when Python called

Tags: python, tcl

So question.

I have a TCL program that is calling a .py program and working as expected.  But the problem is when the full TCL code is run (normal run takes about 3-4 hours), it takes 12-15 hours to run with python (and it is doing nothing difficult or special).  I noticed that when TCL calls the python script, it does not create a .pyc file.  However, when I call the same python script that TCL calls from another python script, I get better performance and a .pyc refresh.

Just curious if TCL-to-Python is limited in this way.  If I need to extend the functionality of my TCL, am I better off using a compiled language such as Java or C?

Edit:

I moved to a team that uses off the shelf product written in TCL.  The software technically works, but it is a maintenance nightmare.  Tens of thousands of lines of code in a single file.  All global variables, no parameters.  Almost no documentation.  All tests, even syntax adjustments, take at least 3 hours.  One errant keystroke can cost you have a workday.  And to top it off, the consultant that wrote it all has left.

What I was attempting to do is extend the software in strategic places while I attempt to make it more maintainable.  Python and TCL seem to work together, which is why I made this attempt.  But this has made me wonder if something like C or Java would be a better try.

I was attempting to write code that I can run and test independently (utilizing MongoDB as the data source) and then plug it in.  Like I said before, it functionally works.  The loop I was testing looped about 230,000 times, so that is why the 10 hour increase I'm sure.

I just come out of a 4 year stint in C#, so that is where my most recent experience lies.  I'm a noob in Python.  There is very little out there regarding TCL-to-C# plug-ins, besides something known as Eclipse that someone wrote years ago.

Comment: .pyc files are only created when an import is done from Python - it never happens for the top-level program.  So if your TCL code is doing something like `exec python foo.py`, you shouldn't expect to see a foo.pyc created.  However, it's hard to imagine this inefficiency costing you *ten hours*, unless there's something else going horribly wrong; I suspect that each invocation of Python is doing too little work to justify the time it takes to start up Python, perhaps you could do the work in larger batches.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to write well-structured, modular code in Tcl.  See e.g. http://nikit.tcl.tk/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+31 . It may be more productive to gradually refactor the working code you've got rather than rewriting in a different language.